# Display var on input field without using the value attribute

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a PHP variable which I am trying to get to appear onto an input field without using the 'value' attribute but I can't seem to get that to work.

I tried a jQuery code I found first to 'append' the variable to the input field but that didn't work.

```
    var first_name = "<?php echo $current_user['first_name']; ?>";
    alert(first_name);
    $('#first_name').val($('#first_name').val() + first_name);
```

I then tried using getElementById but it also didn't work.

```
    var first_name = "<?php echo $current_user['first_name']; ?>";
    alert(first_name);
    document.getElementById('first_name').value = first_name;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

This is the HTML form

```
<form name="personal_form" action="includes/editpersonal.php" method="POST">
   <fieldset>
      <legend><h2>Personal Details</h2></legend>
      <table class="personalform">
         <!--if there is an error on first name, the class name 'form_error_row' will be input into the following tr-->
         <!--allows me to colourise the text field to indicate an error on this row-->
         <tr class="<?php echo form_row_class("first_name") ?>" >
            <th><label for="first_name"><p>First Name: </p></label></th>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" size="40" />
            <!--if there is an error it will print out a div with the error message-->
            <?php echo error_for('first_name') ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>  
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" class="reg-button" value="Update Records" />
</form>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: can u show me the code

Comment: where are the jquery files

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning value in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure html elements are ready for to be accessed by the script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#first_name').val($('#first_name').val() + first_name);
});
```